# Magento: How can i do a if product page then, else if category page then, else if cms page then

Tags: magento

I have a challenge doing the following statement. In breadcrumbs.phtml I would like to do the following:

```
h1
if cms page then getTitle
else if category page then getName
else if product page then getName
/h1
```

Now I figured out these two statements:

```
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getName()?>
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName()?>
```

but I can't figure out how to get them into the `if` statement or how to make the `if` statement entirely.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'cms') {
    // it will return 'cms' string
} else if($this->getProductPage()) {
  // this will check if you are in product page
} else if ($this->getCategoryPage()) {
  // this will check if you are in category page
}
```

<strike>getProductPage</strike> deprecated
<strike>getCategoryPage</strike> deprecated

instead of above code, please try this and let me know result :

```
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms'):
    $Page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle(); 
endif;   

if($Page == 'catalog'):
    $Page->getName();
endif;

if($product = Mage::registry('current_product')):
   $product->getName();
endif;

if($catalog = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'category'))):
   $catalog->getName();
endif;
```

Comment: please check my answer and maybe you can see what i am doing wrong with the above solution?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above advice:

```
<?php
if($this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'cms') {
echo Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle();
} else if($this->getProductPage()) {
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
} else if ($this->getCategoryPage()) {
echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName()
}
?>
```

But it didn't work.

can you see whats wrong?

Comment: where did you use this snippet?

Comment: in breadcrumbs.phtml  -  it actually works on cms pages. but not on product pages nor category pages

Comment: I am so sorry, both method ( getProductPage, getCategoryPage ) has been deprecated ( I checked in 1.6 version )

Comment: oh.. is there any other way to do what i seek?

Comment: nope the above doesn't solve it either. breaks the page. I'm running 1.6.1

Comment: apparantly i can't chat as i don't have enough privileges. i have 11 and need 20 to chat..

Comment: tried logging out and in - tried new browser. chat won't accept my 21 reps.

Comment: `code`(<?php 

if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product'):
$currentproduct = Mage::registry('current_product');
echo $currentproduct->getName();
endif;

if($this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'cms'):
echo Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle();
endif;

if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'category'):
echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
endif;

?>)

Comment: And it wouldn't have been solved without the great help from  Oğuz Çelikdemir